# Create a macro to delete certain files if they are labeled as “approved”

Tags: excel, vba, delete-file

Trying to create a macro to delete certain files that are classified as “approved” in an excel spreadsheet. If they are not approved, I want to skip over that file and move to the next. The files I’m hoping to delete are nestled in sub-folders within the main directory.

[[image: example data]]

I put together a macro based on a few Google searches, but it isn’t working. Right now when I run the macro, nothing happens. There is no error message and none of the files are deleted. I’m pretty new to learning about macros, but I’m wondering what I’m missing.

```
Sub delete_Approved_files()
Const path = "C:\Users\Erkuh\Downloads\Test Files\"
Dim r As Range

Set r = Cells(2, 1)
Do Until r = ""
    If UCase(r.Value) = "APPROVED" Then
        If Dir(path & r.Offset(0, 1)) <> "" Then ' Does the file exist?
            Kill path & r.Offset(0, 1)
        End If
    End If
    Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: @braX updated with my crap code.

Comment: Besides the curly quote problem (the one after "Test Files" is a curly quote, so fix that first, and add a backslash to the end of that string), you are using `UCase` but then comparing it to something that is not all uppercase, so it will never match. I think you want `UCase(r.Value) = "APPROVED"` - and you probably want to start on the 2nd row, so `Set r = Cells(2, 1)`

Comment: @braX getting closer, but still not working. Did a find and replace so APPROVED is all caps in data and in code, fixed curly quotes, starting at 2nd row. Any other ideas?

Comment: `Const path = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Downloads\Test Files\"` (and are you sure that's where the files are?) -- put a breakpoint (F9) on the `Do Until` line and run it. Then when it stops, use F8 to step thru it and check your variables.

Comment: @brax So it is working for the files that are specifically in the downloads folder, but not in any of the sub folders inside. Is there a way to get it to delete all matching approved files in the individual sub folders without listing them?

Comment: VBasic has given you an answer that i'm sure you will do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Delete Files in All Folders and Subfolders (From a List)

```vb
Sub DeleteApproved()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SUB_PATH As String = "\Downloads\Test Files\"
    Const FILE_PATTERN As String = "*.*" ' or e.g. "*.pdf"
    Const INCLUDE_FOLDER_PATH As Boolean = True
    
    Const LKP_SHEET As String = "Sheet1"
    Const LKP_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    Const SRC_COLUMN As String = "B"
    Const LKP_CRITERIA As String = "Approved"
    
    ' Return the file names (keys) and their paths (items) in a dictionary.
    
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & SUB_PATH
    Dim dict As Object:
    Set dict = DictFileNamesPaths(FolderPath, FILE_PATTERN, INCLUDE_FOLDER_PATH)
    
    If dict Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No files found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Write the data to arrays.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(LKP_SHEET)
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = ws.Range(LKP_FIRST_CELL)
    Dim lCell As Range:
    Set lCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, fCell.Column).End(xlUp)
    Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = ws.Range(fCell, lCell)
    ' The following 2 simplified assignments assume at least 2 rows of data.
    Dim lData(): lData = lrg.Value
    Dim sData(): sData = lrg.EntireRow.Columns(SRC_COLUMN).Value
    
    ' Loop and delete.
    
    Dim r As Long, fName As String
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(lData, 1)
        If StrComp(CStr(lData(r, 1)), LKP_CRITERIA, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            fName = CStr(sData(r, 1))
            If dict.Exists(fName) Then
                ' In the Immediate window (Ctrl+G), see what would be deleted.
                ' If that is the requirement, uncomment the kill line.
                Debug.Print fName, dict(fName)
                'Kill dict(fName)
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Inform
    
    MsgBox "Files deleted.", vbInformation
    
End Sub

Function DictFileNamesPaths( _
    ByVal FolderPath As String, _
    Optional ByVal FilePattern As String = "*.*", _
    Optional ByVal IncludeFolderPath As Boolean = True) _
As Object
    Const ProcName As String = "DictFileNamesPaths"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not fso.FolderExists(FolderPath) Then Exit Function
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim coll As Collection: Set coll = New Collection
    coll.Add fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)
    
    Dim fsoFolder As Object ' Current Folder
    Dim fsoSubfolder As Object ' Current Subfolder
    Dim fsoFile As Object ' Current File in the Current Folder

    Do Until coll.Count = 0
        Set fsoFolder = coll(1)
        coll.Remove 1 ' dequeue!
        For Each fsoSubfolder In fsoFolder.SubFolders
            coll.Add fsoSubfolder ' enqueue!
        Next fsoSubfolder
        If IncludeFolderPath Then
            For Each fsoFile In fsoFolder.Files
                If LCase(fsoFile.Name) Like LCase(FilePattern) Then
                    dict(fsoFile.Name) = fsoFile.Path
                End If
            Next fsoFile
        Else
            IncludeFolderPath = True
        End If
    Loop
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Function
    
    Set DictFileNamesPaths = dict

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "@" & ProcName & "@ Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

On the line that starts with Const path, replace "username" with your actual computer username. And it should end with a \ and a proper " mark

```
"C:\Users\Erkuh\Downloads\Test Files\"
```

The line `If UCase(r.Value) = "Approved" Then` will always be false because "Approved" is not an uppercase string. Change it to:

```
If UCase(r.Value) = "APPROVED" Then
```